# DecimalFormat not working for 8233.4892578125 Double value?

Tags: android, number-formatting, decimalformat

I have Double value of my variable is 8233.4892578125 and now when i am passing it to convert it as 8233.5 using below code which is not working as expected .

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.#");
    private String convertToFormat(double value){

        return df.format(value);
    }
```

Now when i pass convertToFormat(8233.4892578125) it give me below output :

> 8233,5

So why this happen it should give me 8233.5 not 8233,5 can any one give me proper answer for this issue.

**NOTE : this issue happen when i have change my android emulator language to Italian from setting.**

Comment: `.` is not `.`. It means decimal separator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it a `Locale` issue. You should supply a local that make uses of the point for the decimal representation. Use a european locale and you should get the point (`Locale.ITALIAN` e.g.).

Edit:

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = (DecimalFormat)
        NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.ITALIAN);
decimalFormat.applyPattern("#.#");
```

Comment: I have change my method by this String.format(current, getString(R.string.distance_calculation),4578.678); in method passing current as Italian it_IT but still it now working

Comment: I'm fairly certain Italian uses `,` for decimal separator. see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:DecimalSeparator.svg

Comment: @blackbelt Thanks i just resolved it by Applying String.format(Locale.US, getString(R.string.distance_calculation),4578.678);